# Why is my custom renderer not working?

Tags: button, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I have the following class in my Droid-Project:

```cs
using MyProject.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(Android.Widget.Button), typeof(ArrowButtonRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.Droid
{
    public class ArrowButtonRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var btn = this.Control as Android.Widget.Button;
            btn.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
        }
    }
}
```

I know, you dont need a custom renderer for changing a button's color, but I just wanna try things out :)

Cheers!

Edit: Here's the code about how I add the button's to the UI:

```cs
MyStackLayout.Children.Add(new Button
{
    Text = "My Button Text"
});
```

And some buttons through xaml:

```xml
<Button x:Name="btnIdk" Text="something" />
```

Comment: Try changing this `typeof(Android.Widget.Button)` to the Xamarin Forms button, so `typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Button)`

Comment: Didn't work, the button has still the color from my style/theme :(

Comment: When you put a breakpoint in there, does it get hit at all?

Comment: Could have tried that earlier, sorry... But no, the breakpoint (at base.OnElementChanged(e);) doesn't get hitted :/

Comment: Do I have to add more stuff in the Xamarin Portable project? I am adding the buttons via C#.

Comment: Please show the code you use to add your buttons to the UI

Comment: Added to my question, @GeraldVersluis

Comment: Hm that all looks fine, pretty sure the ExportRenderer attribute needs to be a `Xamarin.Forms.Button` though. Could you change that and try to clean and rebuild the whole thing? And check if at least the breakpoint gets hit?

Comment: Changed it to this: [assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Button), typeof(ArrowButtonRenderer))]
But there is still no green button. Stil the old color :(
Edit: And breakpoint isn't hitted

Comment: The custom renderer isn't invoked at all! Sorry, added an "Edit" to my last comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123507/discussion-between-gerald-versluis-and-ddertyp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an extensive chat and looking at your sources I've seen that the PCL has version 2.3.1.114 of Xamarin.Forms installed.

Your Droid project has version 1.5.x installed, so it's much older!

Now the next part will be tricky, you need to update your Xamarin.Forms package for Android. But if you update the Xamarin.Android.Support.* packages first, you'll get an error saying that your can't update Xamarin.Forms because no matching version of Forms is found.

Because Xamarin.Forms for Android depends heavily on the support packages they are linked to a specific version, but they're not always in sync. As of right now the Xamarin.Forms version (2.3.2.127) seems to miss the corresponding Android support packages. So don't upgrade to that, upgrade to the same version as your PCL which is 2.3.1.114. Then the Android packages will be updated to 23.3.0 and everything will work nicely.